# Noise in Japanese slot and Pacinko arcades

Tags: japan, local-customs, casinos

I am visiting Japan, I went into a couple of huge Pacinko and slot arcades, just wanted to see them live.

I noticed in both of them a very strong  almost unbearable noise, not coming from the machines, more similar to a jet engine or a huge airflow or a strange white noise. I also noticed big loudspeakers around the arcades.

I know well the noise of video games arcades, this is completely different.

Is it possible that the noise is transmitted through the loudspeakers for some reason related to how there venues work? If this is the case, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about traveling.

Comment: In the US, many (say) banks play white noise in the offices. It is some sort of security measure. (Stops recording supposedly, or something like that.) Perhaps it's related?

Comment: Anecdotal and I may be remembering wrong, but when I visited at 18 I was told that some places played a high pitched sound at the doors to deter young folks from loitering or entering. As you get older you lose the ability to hear the high pitched noise so it only affected terms/early twenties and younger. My younger brother (12) found it actually painful. Maybe this was what you heard?

Comment: You will find this all over Japan (I have found it seems to appear near escalators quite often). I haven't got to the stage where I ask if they are playing high frequency "mosquito sounds" however, you can certainly hear it if your ears are not damaged or aged. I haven't experienced this around Pachinko Parlours though (mainly because both the sounds of the incessant sound of the machines and thick tobacco smoke is a huge turn-off, that and the fact that the Yakuza are usually involved in management. Also note that as per the law, Pachinko is not gambling / a casino, so your tag is wrong.